# Tmux: bad key binding error

Tags: tmux

```
$ tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
bad key: Tab-Space
unknown key: Tab-Space
```

What's up? I checked the man page. `Tab` and `Space` are valid. Why doesn't this combination work when `C-b` works?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Rather `Tab`, use `T`. Stackexchange is too slow nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The `tab-space` would be *two* characters, which tmux does not support.  See [manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1):

> tmux may be controlled from an attached client by using a key combination of a prefix key, ‘C-b’ (Ctrl-b) by default, followed by a command key.

That is, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> is a special case; no other two-character sequences can be bound (unless you change the prefix key, of course).

Comment: Should have been more clear. I wanted to change the prefix key.